# Rocket Simulator in Unity: I don't know how to calculate the delta V

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics

I made a very simple rocket simulator in unity 2d, but out of all the features, I couldn't get the delta V to work. I pre-calculated it before the launch, but when the rocket got empty of fuel, it had an other result.

Here is the entire code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PhysicsScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector2 weight;
    Vector2 thrustForce;
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Vector2 netForce;
    Vector2 dragForce;
    float fuelConsumption;
    float altitude;
    bool enginesToggle;
    float dragRatio;
    bool TurnL;
    bool TurnR;
    float ThrustPercentage;
    bool shiftHeld;
    float yVel;
    float xVel;


    public float fuel;
    public float fuelDensity;
    public float g;
    public float rocketMass;
    public float massFlowRate;
    public float exhaustVelocity;
    public float dragCoefficient;
    public float maxAtmosphereAlt;
    public float TurningForce;

    public Text AltitudeText;
    public Slider thrustSlider;
    public Text Percentage;
    public Text VerticalVel;
    public Text HorizontalVel;
    public Slider fuelSlider;
    public Text FuelPercentage;
    public Text BTDisplayer;
    public Text WTRat;
    public Text WeightD;
    public Text ThrustD;
    public Text MassD;
    public Text DelataVD;
    public Image engineOnOff;
    public Text tti;
    public Text APoapsis;
    public Text dragD;

    float burnTime;
    float W_TRatio;
    float secondsBeforeHittingGround;
    float apoapsis;
    float deltaV;
    float finalMass;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        fuelSlider.maxValue = fuel;
        fuelSlider.value = fuelSlider.maxValue;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        yVel = rb.velocity.y;
        xVel = rb.velocity.x;

        fuelSlider.value = fuel;
        FuelPercentage.text = (fuel * 100 / fuelSlider.maxValue).ToString("0") + "%";

        VerticalVel.text = "Vertical Velocity: " + yVel.ToString("0") + " m/s";
        HorizontalVel.text = "Horizontal Velocity: " + xVel.ToString("0") + " m/s";

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            enginesToggle = !enginesToggle;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            TurnR = true;
        }
        else
        {
            TurnR = false;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            TurnL = true;
        }
        else
        {
            TurnL = false;
        }
        AltitudeText.text = "Altitude: " + altitude.ToString("0") + " m";

        float scroll = Input.GetAxis("Mouse ScrollWheel");
        shiftHeld = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift);

        if (shiftHeld && scroll != 0)
        {
            thrustSlider.value += scroll / 10;
        }
        else if (scroll != 0)
        {
            thrustSlider.value += scroll / 3;
        }

        ThrustPercentage = thrustSlider.value;
        ThrustPercentage = Mathf.Clamp(ThrustPercentage, 0, 1);
        Percentage.text = "Thrust \n" + (thrustSlider.value * 100).ToString("F1") + "%";
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.mass = rocketMass + fuel * fuelDensity;
        if (altitude > maxAtmosphereAlt)
        {
            dragCoefficient = 0;
        }
        dragRatio = altitude / maxAtmosphereAlt;
        //weight
        weight = rb.mass * g * Vector2.down;
        //drag
        dragForce = dragCoefficient * Mathf.Pow(rb.velocity.magnitude, 2) * -rb.velocity;

        //fuel and mass consumptions
        fuelConsumption = exhaustVelocity * massFlowRate * ThrustPercentage;

        altitude = transform.position.y;
        if (fuel > 0 && enginesToggle)
        {
            //thrust
            thrustForce = transform.up * fuelConsumption * exhaustVelocity * ThrustPercentage;
            fuel -= fuelConsumption * Time.deltaTime;
            engineOnOff.color = Color.green;
            apoapsis = 0;
            secondsBeforeHittingGround = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            thrustForce = Vector2.zero;
            engineOnOff.color = Color.red;
            apoapsis = Mathf.Pow(yVel, 2) / Mathf.Pow(g, 2);
            secondsBeforeHittingGround = apoapsis * 2 / g;
        }

        //net 
        netForce = (weight + thrustForce + dragForce) * Time.fixedDeltaTime;
        rb.velocity += netForce / rb.mass;

        fuel = Mathf.Clamp(fuel, 0, fuel);
        dragCoefficient = Mathf.Lerp(dragCoefficient, 0, dragRatio * Time.fixedDeltaTime);

        if (TurnR)
        {
            rb.AddTorque(-TurningForce * rb.mass);
        }

        if (TurnL)
        {
            rb.AddTorque(TurningForce * rb.mass);
        }
        rb.AddTorque(-4 * rb.angularVelocity * rb.mass * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        burnTime = fuel / fuelConsumption;

        W_TRatio = (exhaustVelocity * massFlowRate * ThrustPercentage) / weight.magnitude;

        BTDisplayer.text = "Burn Time: " + burnTime.ToString("0") + "s";
        WTRat.text = "T/W Ratio: " + W_TRatio.ToString("F2") + "x";

        WeightD.text = "Weight: " + weight.magnitude.ToString("0") + "N";
        ThrustD.text = "Thrust: " + (exhaustVelocity * massFlowRate *   ThrustPercentage).ToString("0") + "N";
        deltaV = Mathf.Log(rb.mass / rocketMass) * massFlowRate * exhaustVelocity;
        MassD.text = rb.mass.ToString("0") + "kg";
        DelataVD.text = "work in progress..";

        tti.text = "Time to Apoapsis: " + (secondsBeforeHittingGround).ToString("0") + "s";
        APoapsis.text = "Distance Apoapsis: " + apoapsis.ToString("0") + "m";
        dragD.text = "Drag: " + Mathf.Clamp((100 - (altitude * 100 / maxAtmosphereAlt)), 0, 100).ToString("F1") + "%";
    }
}
```

Hopefully it isn't that hard to read.

I calculated the delta V using a calculator, the when the simulated rocket emptied, its velocity wasn't even close to what I expected. I made a lot of tweaks with the code, which made it worse, so I undo-ed them.
[On Launch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhyqZ.png)
[max velocity reached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D0avx.png)

So, as you can see I had 1000 fuel on me. With the fuel density of 0.3, the mass of the fuel will be 300. The rocket also has 10kg. That will be 310kg in total. No drag or gravity forces are exerted on the rocket. The exhaust velocity is 100. If delta V = Ln(m0/mf)*ve, then deltaV = Ln(310/10)*100,
deltaV = Ln(31)*100, deltaV = 3.43*100, results the DeltaV = 343 m/s, when in fact, my max velocity was 1150.
Help?

Comment: Is this really a programming or rather a maths/physics question? Maybe better suited for [math](https://math.stackexchange.com) or [physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com) communities?

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm applies both drag and weight, but your description of your equation ignores them.

Comment: In this state this looks more like a comment tbh

Comment: Succinct answers are still answers ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯